# PHP/MySQL: How to create/access one database connection within objects?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project where I have several different classes that need to connect to a MySQL database. My question is how do I accomplish this from inside the instantiated classes efficiently. I've read that opening and closing multiple connections is a bad idea and using globals also isn't a great option... So what other options are there? Is there a standard or best practive for accessing databases in this kind of situation? I'm still a beginning programmer.

Comment: please upload your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Establish a connection then pass that connection object to each of the classes that require it as an argument to the constructor.

```
class myClass {

 function __construct($db) {
  $this->db = $db;
 }
 function doStuff($someQuery) {
  $result = $this->db->query($someQuery);
  // fetch data here...
  return $someData;
 }
}
```

Then

```
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
$someObject = new myClass($db);
$data = $someObject->doStuff($myQuery);
```

Comment: OK, so then when I pass off the connection as a parameter, it would just be getting passed off as a _reference_ to the original connection, is that right?

Comment: That's precisely what happens

Comment: I take it this works just as well if I created a class for my database connection and passed off the object as a parameter?

Comment: That'll depend on the class you create, but in principle it should be fine.

Comment: Could you expand on that? If I create a class, should I create a static class just so I can ensure there's only one instance of that class? And would you say creating a class is a better option or just creating a normal connection like you specified in your answer? Is there any downsides, such as security concerns or anything?

Comment: A static class is not instantiated, so there are no copies. I don't see how you'd make that work. A class that properly encapsulates its code with no side effects should be fine. I don't have a view on what's better - that's really down to what you're trying to achieve. I don't know of any security concerns with creating a class for this, but the devil is always in the detail. Your specific implementation might have a weakness somewhere - I wouldn't know.